# How should I organize normal and "state" versions of functions in the state monad?

Tags: haskell

I decided to try the State Monad to try and clean up some of the projects that I've started. I ran into a naming/compartmentalization problem.

If I have the following objects:

```
data Obj = Player { oPos :: Point }

data World = World { wKeys :: [Key], wPlayer :: Obj }
```

I might have a convenience function like:

```
setPlayer :: Obj -> World -> World
setPlayer o w = w{wPlayer = o}
```

and a matching state operation like:

```
setPlayerW :: Obj -> WorldState ()
setPlayerW o = get >>= put . setPlayer o
```

which uses the other convenience function; for convenience.

What is the typical naming convention for something like this? I post-pended the state version with a W, but that's kind of ugly.

And are the "state-versions" typical segregated from the "object-versions" in a separate file?

Am I going about this wrong completely? Is there a better set-up then having 2 different versions of any operations I might need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't have a separate function for the state version myself. Instead, use the [`modify`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:modify) function instead:

```
do let o = player
   modify (setPlayer o)
   something else
```

In a sense, the naming convention you're looking for would just be the same as using `modify` except folded into the names of each function. When I find myself naming functions like this, I generally try to find some way to organize them *in* the language instead of using their names. Sometimes, like here, an existing function is all you need; other times, it involves creating a function of your own to achieve the same end or extracting things into a module.

The core idea is that it's better to reify patterns in your code using first-class language constructs instead of encoding them indirectly into the names. (Of course, if this ends up really awkward, you shouldn't do it, but it's fine here.)

Comment: I'm assuming modify is a higher order that replaces the state with whatever the result of the passed function is? I didn't even think about just generalizing it. Thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Yep, that's exactly what `modify` does. It's a very handy function for work with `State`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I need to get in the habit of identifying potential patterns. If you found that you were using a particular function with `modify` a lot, would you then alias it (`setPlayerW o = modify (setPlayer o)`), or just leave it for consistency?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I probably wouldn't, because the pattern of `modify (setPlayer o)` is clear and easy to read on its own. You win relatively little by giving it a separate name, and just obscure what's going on. The one exception is if there is some semantic reason to give the function a special name (like `nextTurn` instead of `setPlayerW` or something), in which case that's what I'd use.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a good time to introduce the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.4.0.2) library.  This is a bit of a daunting library at first, and I still struggle with some of its more complex features (the rabbit hole is pretty deep for this one), but it can really simplify a lot of your `State` code.  To use it, it's recommended to change your data types a bit first so you can utilize template haskell:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Lens

-- Made assumption on what Point would look like
data Point = Point { _x :: Int, _y :: Int } deriving (Eq, Show)
data Obj = Player { _oPos :: Point } deriving (Eq, Show)
data World = World { _wKeys :: [Key], _wPlayer :: Obj } deriving (Eq, Show)

makeLenses ''Point
makeLenses ''Obj
makeLenses ''World

-- Also assumed this type
type WorldState = StateT World IO
```

Then you can write code that looks very much imperative using the generated lenses

```
setPlayerW :: Obj -> WorldState ()
setPlayerW o = wPlayer .= o
```

Or if you want the non-monadic version

```
setPlayer :: Obj -> World -> World
setPlayer o = wPlayer .~ o
```

So this uses the `.=` operator to set the `wPlayer` field of the `World` state to the new value.  More impressively, you could use it to write code like

```
moveUp, moveDown, moveLeft, moveRight :: WorldState ()
moveUp    = wPlayer.oPos.y += 1
moveDown  = wPlayer.oPos.y -= 1
moveLeft  = wPlayer.oPos.x -= 1
moveRight = wPlayer.oPos.x += 1
```

Which makes it look a lot like an object oriented language using normal function composition.  A quick test:

```
game :: WorldState ()
game = do
    replicateM_ 3 moveUp
    replicateM_ 5 moveLeft
    replicateM_ 10 moveRight
    replicateM_ 6 moveDown

> execStateT game $ World [] $ Player $ Point 0 0
World {_wKeys = [], _wPlayer = Player {_oPos = Point {_x = 5, _y = -3}}}
```

There are a lot of really interesting and useful operators in the lens library, and there's a lot of support built-in for using it with `StateT` stacks.

Another nice feature is the `zoom` function, which takes a lens and "zooms in" on it, letting you operate as if your state has the value of whatever you zoomed onto.  An example would be

```
game = zoom (wPlayer.oPos) $ do
    y += 3
    x -= 5
    x += 10
    y -= 6
```

And this would produce the same result as before.  This is generally more efficient (fewer layers to unwrap at each step) and can be much cleaner.

Comment: I've read a few times that unless the project is sufficiently complicated already, adding lens will just complicate things. I don't think that anything I'm currently working on can justify it, but it is on my list of things to learn. Thanks for the suggestion.